# How can I modify the AD template to get key encipherment key usage?

Tags: active-directory, certificate, x509certificate

I am using Active Directory to generate an ECDSA certificate of 256 bits and I need it to have the key encipherment key usage but even as I can see the configuration choosen has that option the certificate doesn't have it. What am I missing?

This is how my key usage tab looks:

[image]

But this is how the resulting certificate looks:

[image]

I've tried changing the allow encryption data option but the result is the same, is there somewhere else to force this key usage?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In ECC, key encipherment is no longer used for online key encryption (e.g. in TLS), key agreement is used instead.

Comment: Do you know why key agreement is used instead of key encipherment? I haven't been able to find the reason _why_.

Comment: Key agreement is more secure way to protect session keys and include features such as forward secrecy and others.